# undefined reference to `WinMain@16'

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

When I try to build a program using `Eclipse CDT`, I get the following:

> /mingw/lib/libmingw32.a(main.o):main.c:(.text+0x106):
>   undefined reference to `WinMain@16

Why is that? And, how can I solve this issue?

Comment: try to save your file and re run in my case it workied

Comment: In my case it was a file without the int main() {} function

Answer (score 204):

This error occurs when the linker can't find `WinMain` function, so it is probably missing. In your case, you are probably missing `main` too.

Consider the following Windows API-level program:

```
#define NOMINMAX
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    MessageBox( 0, "Blah blah...", "My Windows app!", MB_SETFOREGROUND );
}
```

Now let's build it using GNU toolchain (i.e. g++), no special options. Here `gnuc` is just a batch file that I use for that. It only supplies options to make g++ more standard:

```
C:\test> gnuc x.cpp

C:\test> objdump -x a.exe | findstr /i "^subsystem"
Subsystem               00000003        (Windows CUI)

C:\test> _
```

This means that the linker by default produced a **console subsystem** executable. The **subsystem** value in the file header tells Windows what services the program requires. In this case, with console system, that the program requires a console window.

This also causes the command interpreter to wait for the program to complete.

Now let's build it with **GUI subsystem**, which just means that the program does not require a console window:

```
C:\test> gnuc x.cpp -mwindows

C:\test> objdump -x a.exe | findstr /i "^subsystem"
Subsystem               00000002        (Windows GUI)

C:\test> _
```

Hopefully that's OK so far, although the `-mwindows` flag is just semi-documented.

Building without that semi-documented flag one would have to more specifically tell the linker which subsystem value one desires, and some Windows API import libraries will then in general have to be specified explicitly:

```
C:\test> gnuc x.cpp -Wl,-subsystem,windows

C:\test> objdump -x a.exe | findstr /i "^subsystem"
Subsystem               00000002        (Windows GUI)

C:\test> _
```

That worked fine, with the GNU toolchain.

But what about the Microsoft toolchain, i.e. Visual C++?

Well, building as a console subsystem executable works fine:

```
C:\test> msvc x.cpp user32.lib
x.cpp

C:\test> dumpbin /headers x.exe | find /i "subsystem" | find /i "Windows"
               3 subsystem (Windows CUI)

C:\test> _
```

However, with Microsoft's toolchain building as GUI subsystem does not work by default:

```
C:\test> msvc x.cpp user32.lib /link /subsystem:windows
x.cpp
LIBCMT.lib(wincrt0.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _WinMain@16 referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartu
p
x.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

C:\test> _
```

Technically this is because Microsoft’s linker *is non-standard by default for GUI subsystem*. By default, when the subsystem is GUI, then Microsoft's linker uses a runtime library **entry point**, the function where the machine code execution starts, called `winMainCRTStartup`, that calls Microsoft's non-standard **`WinMain`** instead of standard `main`.

No big deal to fix that, though.

All you have to do is to tell Microsoft's linker which entry point to use, namely `mainCRTStartup`, which calls standard `main`:

```
C:\test> msvc x.cpp user32.lib /link /subsystem:windows /entry:mainCRTStartup
x.cpp

C:\test> dumpbin /headers x.exe | find /i "subsystem" | find /i "Windows"
               2 subsystem (Windows GUI)

C:\test> _
```

No problem, but very tedious. And so arcane and hidden that most Windows programmers, who mostly only use Microsoft’s non-standard-by-default tools, do not even know about it, and mistakenly think that a Windows GUI subsystem program “must” have non-standard `WinMain` instead of standard `main`. In passing, with C++0x Microsoft will have a problem with this, since the compiler must then advertize whether it's free-standing or hosted (when hosted it must support standard `main`).

Anyway, that's the reason why g++ *can* complain about `WinMain` missing: it's a silly non-standard startup function that Microsoft's tools require by default for GUI subsystem programs.

But as you can see above, g++ has no problem with standard `main` even for a GUI subsystem program.

So what could be the problem?

Well, you are probably *missing* a `main`. And you probably have no (proper) `WinMain` either! And then g++, after having searched for `main` (no such), and for Microsoft's non-standard `WinMain` (no such), reports that the latter is missing.

Testing with an empty source:

```
C:\test> type nul >y.cpp

C:\test> gnuc y.cpp -mwindows
c:/program files/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.1/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):main.c:(.text+0xd2): undefined referen
ce to `WinMain@16'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

C:\test> _
```

Comment: @Alf P. Steinbach. Thanks so much for your nice reply. As for `All you have to do is to tell Microsoft's linker which entry point to use, namely mainCRTStartup, which calls standard main`. Is there a way to do that `Eclipse CDT` as I'm not using the command line. Thanks

Comment: @user588855: since you're using g++ that (probably) does not apply to you. Only the part at the end (probably) applies. That is, define a `main` or a `WinMain`, or, make sure that the relevant file is included in the project. Cheers,

Comment: @Alf P. Steinbach. What do you mean by defining `main` or `winmain`? Thanks

Comment: @user588855: the example program at the top of the answer shows a standard `main` function. You need that in your program (but with some other body). Or, you might use a non-standard Microsoft `WinMain`, but you need to have one of them, and the file needs to be included in the project.

Comment: I just made a file called main.cpp that had the code:
int main()
{
}

Comment: instead of `-mwindows` one could use `-mconsole`, if only CLI interface is used.

Comment: Since you asked for it: This downvote is for the misinformation sprinkled throughout this entire answer. Maybe you should resist answering Windows-specific questions until you can cope with facts (such as: GCC is no more conforming than MSVC).

Comment: @IInspectable the answer was written in 2011, in that time MSVC not only wasn't conforming, it was using alternate versions of features (i.e. alternate syntax) compared to ISO standard, or literally misbehaviour, e.g. a class derived from a trivially-initialized class would not initialize fields of parent same way as standard prescribes.

Comment: @IInspectable: You present an incorrect assertion that "GCC is no more conforming than MSVC", that I believe you have to KNOW is false. If you didn't know it's false, then you had to KNOW that you didn't know anything about it, and yet presented that as fact. MinGW g++ accepts a standard `main` also for a GUI subsystem build; Visual C++ 2022 by default does not. I.e. with respect to `main` function issue, g++ is standard-conforming and Visual C++ is not (by default).

Comment: GCC today is what MSVC used to be prior to 2010: A delivery channel for non-conforming behavior. As far as [C++20 core language features](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support#cpp20) and [C++20 library features](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support#cpp20) go, MSVC is all green. GCC... well. What am I missing?

Comment: @IInspectable: MinGW g++ accepts a standard main also for a GUI subsystem build; Visual C++ 2022 by default does not. I.e. with respect to main function issue, g++ is standard-conforming and Visual C++ is not (by default). It would be nice with fewer comments about irrelevant issues that you somehow associate with this.

Comment: @yoelhalb Nothing changed. This post has always been dogmatic, trying to convince us of the great benefits of having a cross-platform entry point name. It proposes a solution relying on wildly unspecified compiler internals for no apparent reason. It distinctly avoids proposing The Solution: Provide an entry point that the build tools expect, i.e., `WinMain`.

Comment: @IInspectable: using standard C++ is good. Using `WinMain` is unnecessary and pretty dumb.

Comment: *"Using `WinMain` is unnecessary"* - You haven't made a convincing point about why that is the case. An out-of-spec use of CRT internals doesn't make for a sustainable argument. You are just being dogmatic, repeating the *"Standard C++ is Good"* mantra without considering what makes it so: Portability. But then, the [entry point](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function) is *literally defined as non-portable*. `int main(HINSTANCE, HINSTANCE, LPCWSTR, int)` is a perfectly valid signature. It has the name `main`. And is non-portable. What's the dogmatist's response to that?

Answer (score 84):

To summarize the above post by Cheers and hth. - Alf, Make sure you have `main()` or `WinMain()` defined and g++ should do the right thing.

My problem was that `main()` was defined inside of a namespace by accident.

Comment: Just realized something important about all this. In my case, it was not finding main() since I did not declare any arguments (argc, argv). Once added, it found main. Also, the nature of how this works means that mingw is trying to help by providing its own main which in turn calls WinMain. GUI programs would only have WinMain and the main stub in mingw is used to get there. If you have a main, then it uses that instead.

Comment: extern "C" int main(void) fixed the problem for me

Comment: @driedler [`basic.start.main`](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.start.main#2.sentence-2) - _"Its type **shall have C++ language linkage** and it shall have a declared return type of type int, but otherwise its type is implementation-defined."_ - so if you had to give it C linkage, something seems wrong.

Answer (score 38):

I was encountering this error while compiling my application with SDL. This was caused by SDL defining it's own main function in SDL_main.h. To prevent SDL define the main function an SDL_MAIN_HANDLED macro has to be defined before the SDL.h header is included.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This command works: gcc main.c -I"E:\Libs\SDL2-devel-2.0.12-mingw\SDL2-2.0.12\i686-w64-mingw32\include" -I"E:\Libs\SDL2_ttf-devel-2.0.15-mingw\SDL2_ttf-2.0.15\i686-w64-mingw32\include" -L"E:\Libs\SDL2-devel-2.0.12-mingw\SDL2-2.0.12\i686-w64-mingw32\lib" -L"E:\Libs\SDL2_ttf-devel-2.0.15-mingw\SDL2_ttf-2.0.15\i686-w64-mingw32\lib" -lSDL2 -lSDL2main -lSDL2_ttf -o app.exe

Answer (score 16):

Try saving your .c file before building. I believe your computer is referencing a path to a file with no information inside of it.

Answer (score 4):

My situation was that I did not have a main function.

Answer (score 0):

Had same problem. To fix it I clicked save to save my .c file before building. I believe my computer was referencing a path to a file with no information inside of it.

Answer (score -1):

**Check that All Files are Included in Your Project:**

I had this same error pop up after I updated cLion. After hours of tinkering, I noticed one of my files was not included in the project target. After I added it back to the active project, I stopped getting the undefined reference to winmain16, and the code compiled.

Edit: It's also worthwhile to check the build settings within your IDE.

*(Not sure if this error is related to having recently updated the IDE - could be causal or simply correlative. Feel free to comment with any insight on that factor!)*