# How to compile .c code from Cython with gcc

Tags: python, c, gcc, compilation, cython

Now that I've successfully installed Cython on Windows 7, I try to compile some Cython code using Cython, but gcc makes my life hard.

```
cdef void say_hello(name):
    print "Hello %s" % name
```

Using gcc to compile the code throws dozens of **undefined reference to** -erros, and I'm pretty sure the `libpython.a` is available (as the installation tutorial said, *undefined reference to* -errors are thrown if this file is missing).

```
$ cython ctest.pyx
$ gcc ctest.c -I"C:\Python27\include"
```

```
C:\Users\niklas\AppData\Local\Temp\cckThGrF.o:ctest.c:(.text+0x1038): undefined reference to `_imp__PyString_FromStringAndSize'
C:\Users\niklas\AppData\Local\Temp\cckThGrF.o:ctest.c:(.text+0x1075): undefined reference to `_imp___Py_TrueStruct'
C:\Users\niklas\AppData\Local\Temp\cckThGrF.o:ctest.c:(.text+0x1086): undefined reference to `_imp___Py_ZeroStruct'
C:\Users\niklas\AppData\Local\Temp\cckThGrF.o:ctest.c:(.text+0x1099): undefined reference to `_imp___Py_NoneStruct'
C:\Users\niklas\AppData\Local\Temp\cckThGrF.o:ctest.c:(.text+0x10b8): undefined reference to `_imp__PyObject_IsTrue'
c:/program files/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.2/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):main.c:(.text+0xd2): undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The weird thing is, using `pyximport`* or a `setup`-script works pretty fine, but it's both not very handy when still working on a module.

### **How to compile those `.c` files generated with Cython using gcc ?**

*or any other compiler, important is that it will work !*

`*pyximport`: Is it normal that only python-native functions and classes are contained in the imported module and not cdef-functions and classes ?
like:

```
# filename: cython_test.pyx
cdef c_foo():
    print "c_foo !"
def foo():
    print "foo !"
    c_foo()
```

```
import pyximport as p; p.install()
import cython_test
cython_test.foo()
# foo !\nc_foo !
cython_test.c_foo()
# AttributeError, module object has no attribute c_foo
```

### **UPDATE**

Calling `$ gcc ctest.c "C:\Python27\libs\libpython27.a"` kills the **undefined reference to** -erros, but this one:

```
c:/program files/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.2/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):main.c:(.text+0xd2): undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
```

Comment: The "undefined reference to `WinMain@16'" means that the gcc is looking (without luck) for the "main" entry point. See for instance http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5259714/undefined-reference-to-winmain16

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try:

```
gcc -c -IC:\Python27\include -o ctest.o ctest.c
gcc -shared -LC:\Python27\libs -o ctest.pyd ctest.o -lpython27
```

`-shared` creates a shared library. `-lpython27` links with the import library C:\Python27\libs\libpython27.a.

Comment: Awesome, the .pyd file did compile ! I can include it to python.
Can't cdefs be called from python ? So I do have to write a def-wrapper for every cdef ? I'll check this out !

Comment: VERY IMPORTANT: if `-lpython27` is placed before the `ctest.c -o ctest.pyd` it just does not work...

Comment: @SaulloCastro: I edited the command to try to make the order more clear.

Answer (score 1):

That is a linker (ld) error and not a compiler error. You should provide the path to the library (-l and -L) and not only to the headers (-I).

Comment: unfortunately, adding `-L"C:\Python27\libs"` does not fix this problem.

Comment: using `-I"C:\Python27\libs\libpython.a"`, gcc tells me that -I is not a directory. **BTW**: please notice the updated question.

Comment: it's a lowercase L, not an uppercase i

Comment: Ah, sorry. Doing so (`gcc ctest.c -l "C:\Python27\libs\libpython27.a"`) causes this error, really confusing. This file exists. `c:/program files/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.2/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lC:\Python27\libs\libpython27.a`

Comment: Thanks for your help anyway, eryksun's version works just fine. :)

Comment: yes the "version" is the same, -L is the path to the library dir and -l specifies the name of the library :-)

Comment: oh.. I understand. lol. I thougt I should add the full path to `-l`. You'll earn a +1 as well. :)