# Compile .c files to .pyd

Tags: python, c

I used Cython to convert a `.pyx` file to `.c`. Now, I'm trying to compile it to `.pyd`, using the `tcc` compiler:

```
C:\Users\USER>"C:\Program Files\tcc\tcc.exe" tkExtra.c -o tkExtra.pyd -
shared -IC\Python27\include -LC\Python27\libs -lpython27
```

However, I get this error:

```
tkExtra.c:8: error: include file 'pyconfig.h' not found
```

`C:\Python27\include` does have `pyconfig.h`. I had looked at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6987419/1730261) to get the command line code for this, only substituting `gcc` with `tcc`.

How can I fix this, or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Your path flags say `C\Python27` instead of `C:\Python27`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems like you're missing some colons. Try:

```
C:\Users\USER>"C:\Program Files\tcc\tcc.exe" tkExtra.c -o tkExtra.pyd -shared -IC:\Python27\include -LC:\Python27\libs -lpython27
```