# call cython generated so file or c file in fortran

Tags: python, fortran, cython

probably I have taken a long route, but for some reason, I have to call a python routine from fortran. So, I have use `cython`.
Cython has generated the C code.

As per cython document, I tried to compile the code. The shared lib (.so) file is generated without problem, but I cant compile the C file to executable.

I tried compiling it using info given [here](http://docs.cython.org/src/reference/compilation.html).
I have also checked the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6985109/how-to-compile-c-code-from-cython-with-gcc), but in my linux system, the libpython does not exist(may be somwhere else to look at?)

```
gcc -c -I/usr/include/python3.4/ parse.c
gcc  -I/usr/include/python3.4m/  -L/usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/ parse.c -lpython
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpython
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

So, is there any way to compile the C file generated by python? Or, alternatively, can I use the generated so file(I guess I need the lpython any way).

So, at present, the question is:

1. How to compile C code generated by cython?
2. where I can found the libpython.so if fedora-linux?

   The pyx (or the python code is:) https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B02WblgE6NEvenNYT1RoVmMyM3M/view?usp=sharing
   (Somehow the code formatting here did not worked, so, uploaded it in drive)

Comment: On my system, I don't have a `libpython.so`. Instead, I have `libpython2.7.so` and `libpython3.4m.so`. It is located in /usr/lib64/``. Maybe you should try `-lpython3.4m` and, if this folder is not already searched by default `-L/usr/lib64/`!

Comment: Thanks. Bit thats giving me error: 
`gcc -L/usr/lib64/  parse.o -lpython2.7
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.9.2/../../../../lib64/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

Comment: You are trying to compile it as a main program. You must use `-c`.