# Converting .c file from Cython to standalone .exe And compilation gcc error

Tags: python, c, gcc, mingw, cython

This is 2 separate errors in single question.
I followed the docs on Cython website on how to build a cython script. I Created .pyx file, did `cython -a filename.pyx --embed` to create .c file and then

```
import pyximport; pyximport.install()
import filename
```

to run my simple hello world program.

Now I want to implement cython on Random Forest and I use the following modules while importing :

```
from __future__ import division
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
import pymysql
import datetime
import csv
from operator import itemgetter
from sklearn.metrics import *
from algoScore import algo_score
import sys
```

When I try to do **cython -a randomforest.pyx ** is showed some errors regarding **numpy** so I thought since numpy used c headers, I need to build using distutils by providing include_path in setup.py ([Following this link](http://docs.cython.org/src/reference/compilation.html)) and the following is my setup.py :

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize
import numpy

setup(
    name = "Test script",
    ext_modules = cythonize('randomforest.pyx', include_path = [numpy.get_include()]),  # accepts a glob pattern
)
```

when I try building the file from command line by following command :

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

I get following errors :

```
running build_ext
building 'randomforest' extension
c:\mingw\bin\gcc.exe -mdll -O -Wall -IC:\Python27\include -IC:\Python27\PC -c randomforest.c -o build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\randomforest.o
writing build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\randomforest.def
c:\mingw\bin\gcc.exe -shared -s build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\randomforest.o build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\randomforest.def -LC:\Python27\libs -LC:\Python27\PCbuild -lpython27 -lmsvcr90 -o "e:\PA - Project\CodeBase\Tests\balanceClasses\balanceClasses\RF\randomforest.pyd"
C:\Python27\libs/libpython27.a(dmmes00976.o):(.idata$7+0x0): undefined reference to `_head_C__build27_cpython_PCBuild_libpython27_a'
C:\Python27\libs/libpython27.a(dmmes00239.o):(.idata$7+0x0): undefined reference to `_head_C__build27_cpython_PCBuild_libpython27_a'
C:\Python27\libs/libpython27.a(dmmes00236.o):(.idata$7+0x0): undefined reference to `_head_C__build27_cpython_PCBuild_libpython27_a'
C:\Python27\libs/libpython27.a(dmmes00245.o):(.idata$7+0x0): undefined reference to `_head_C__build27_cpython_PCBuild_libpython27_a'
C:\Python27\libs/libpython27.a(dmmes00343.o):(.idata$7+0x0): undefined reference to `_head_C__build27_cpython_PCBuild_libpython27_a'
C:\Python27\libs/libpython27.a(dmmes00386.o):(.idata$7+0x0): more undefined references to `_head_C__build27_cpython_PCBuild_libpython27_a' follow
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command 'c:\\mingw\\bin\\gcc.exe' failed with exit status 1
```

Also, though error are generated, I do get a .c file generated and .def & .o files as well.

I want to know weather the file is compiler? Can I run it from pyximport by importing or not? And also, if I can't then is there any specific way to compile the .c file using any compiler into standalone .exe?

I tried using VC++ command line by compiler /c and I had faced the issue as described in [following link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32354762/unable-to-compile-cython-generated-c-file?noredirect=1#comment52610679_32354762) (Edit 1).

Would be grateful if someone an help me as I've been facing this since long and even googling doesn't seem to give any answer.

Answer (score 1):

I got a similar error message when I tried to build simple "hello world" program (http://omake.accense.com/static/doc-ja/cython/src/quickstart/build.html) with cython and cygwin GCC.

In my case, using VC compiler solved this problem.

1)Install Visual C++ for Python from Microsoft(http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44266)

2)Add its installed registry to PATH (install registry was C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python in my environment)

3)Create config file (C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\distutils.cfg).
Then write following text in it.

```
[build_ext]
compiler=msvc
```

4)Then compile with cython.

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```