# How do you compile python 3.5 code with Mingw?

Tags: python, windows, mingw, python-3.5

I've spent a rather long time today trying to compile a pyd for `python 3.5` on `windows 10` using code generated with `cython`.  I know one can do it with `MSVS` but I want to use `mingw` instead because I don't want to download too much junk.  I've searched around and I've found this SO question: [How to compile .c code from Cython with gcc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6985109/how-to-compile-c-code-from-cython-with-gcc)
I've tried to follow the accepted answer (changing all the `Python27's` to `Python35`) but to no use.  I see it does work with `python 2.7` though, so I was wondering why it doesn't work properly on `3.5`.  If anybody could help me with this issue, it would be magnificent.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

`mingwpy` still doesn't have support for Python 3.5, but it'll change some day.

[See `Specific Notes` section](https://github.com/winpython/winpython/issues/217)

[UPD: mingwpy for python-3.5 could be provided with a significant limitation](https://github.com/winpython/winpython/issues/67#issuecomment-202584219)