# Qt C++ Project with non-inline assembly

Tags: qt, assembly, qt-creator, qmake

I am using Windows XP, and Newest Qt Creator with QtSDK and the built-in gcc compiler.

The question is, how to use full assembly in a C++ Qt Project.
I know how to use inline assembly, but I don't know how to do non-inline(written in a separate .asm file) full assembly, in a Qt C++ project.

Is this possible with a Qt C++ project, and if so, how?

EDIT:

***pro file**

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= qt

SOURCES += \
    calc.S
```

**calc.S**

```
section .data
        hello: db 'Hello world!', 10
        helloLen: equ $-hello

section .text
        global _start

_start:
        mov eax, 4
        mov ebx, 1
        mov ecx, hello
        mov edx, helloLen
        int 80h

proexit:
        mov eax, 1
        mov ebx, 0
        int 80h
```

**Compile errors**

```
..\plain_cpp\calc.S: Assembler messages:
..\plain_cpp\calc.S:1: Error: no such instruction: `section .data'
..\plain_cpp\calc.S:2: Error: no such instruction: `db 72ello world!4410'
..\plain_cpp\calc.S:3: Error: no such instruction: `equ $-hello'
..\plain_cpp\calc.S:5: Error: no such instruction: `section .text'
..\plain_cpp\calc.S:6: Error: no such instruction: `global _start'
..\plain_cpp\calc.S:9: Error: too many memory references for `mov'
..\plain_cpp\calc.S:10: Error: too many memory references for `mov'
..\plain_cpp\calc.S:11: Error: too many memory references for `mov'
..\plain_cpp\calc.S:12: Error: too many memory references for `mov'
..\plain_cpp\calc.S:13: Error: junk `h' after expression
..\plain_cpp\calc.S:13: Error: suffix or operands invalid for `int'
..\plain_cpp\calc.S:16: Error: too many memory references for `mov'
..\plain_cpp\calc.S:17: Error: too many memory references for `mov'
..\plain_cpp\calc.S:18: Error: junk `h' after expression
..\plain_cpp\calc.S:18: Error: suffix or operands invalid for `int'
```

**EDIT 2 - AT&T Style**

**PRO File**

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= qt

SOURCES += \
    calc.S
```

**calc.S**

```
.data
hello:
    .string "Hello World\n"

.globl  main
main:
    movl $4, %eax
    movl $1, %ebx
    movl $hello,%ecx
    movl $12,%edx
    int $0x80

    ret
```

**ERRORS**

```
undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: This is a linker error. You need to supply the correct `-l` options while linking.

Answer (score 2):

While *@karlphillip* method correct in general, you should take in mind some windows specified stuff:

1. While you compile  *@karlphillip*'s code you get linker error produced by `MinGw` standard library file:

   ```
   c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.1/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o): In function `main':
   C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\src\mingwrt/../mingw/main.c:73: undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
   ```

   That is not your `main`, that is `libmingw32.a`'s main. And it expects `WinMain` as entry point of *your* code. The thing is that `WinMain` is default entry point for windows application defined by Microsoft. `libmingw32.a` defines actual main, that is called from actual entry point. That main does some stuff and than calls `WinMain`. But you have no `WinMain` defined, obviously.

   In this simple example you needn't standard library actually, then you can drop standard library and compile above code with command line

   ```
   gcc -Wl,-subsystem,console 1.S -nostdlib
   ```

   It should be equivalent Qt setting `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS+=-nostdlib`

   Then code above compiles, and... *segfaults*. Then go to point 2:
2. `int 80h` is specific linux system call. Seems it doesn't work on windows. You should invoke `WriteConsole` on windows to write to `stdin`. But as a "proof of concept" you can run the following code:

   ```
   .text
   .globl  main
   main:
       movl $1, %eax
   ret
   ```

   This will set exit code of program to 1.

**EDIT**
If you want *Hello world* example, compiled with standard library included, you can try this:

```
.data
hello:
    .string "Hello World\n"

.text
.global _WinMain@16
_WinMain@16:
    push $hello
    call _puts
    add $4, %esp

    ret
```

Compile with `gcc 1.S`

Comment: Is it possible to use the standard library calls (`puts` for example) WITHOUT using WinMain? I'd like to define `start` or `main` as an entry point. I'm trying to inform the linker to use `main` as an entry point (`-emain`), but it doesn't work: it still demands `WinMain@16`. And when I add `-nostdlib`, then it doesn't recognize `puts` on the other hand ;-/ Where's `puts` located? What lib should I link with?

Comment: @SasQ, Even if you redefine entry point, you still link to standard library and it requires `int main()` defined in your code. If you redefine entry point, this main will never be called. You can just create empty `main()`. But I think you are looking for troubles while trying to use standard library with custom entry point: Custom entry point means initialization code will not be ran, global objects will not be created, probably standard library functions will refuse to work

Comment: I found what I was doing wrong: The linker didn't see my `puts` because I used `_puts` (name mangling), but it appears that on x86_64 target GCC uses no mangling by default (along with other ABI breakages, like using registers for passing parameters etc.). My code was written for x86 (32-bit) which uses different call conventions (name mangling, pushing parameters on the stack etc.). From the same reasons it didn't see my `main` function, which I had called `_main`. After those changes it worked. Huh... One needs to learn all life long... :-P

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you read [this tutorial](http://dvisagie.blogspot.com/2011/09/setting-up-qt-creator-for-assemblylinux.html) to properly setup Qt Creator for assembly.

**EDIT:**

Your problem is that **qmake** will call **gcc** to compile your assembly code, and you are using **Intel Syntax**. You need to **convert your assembly code to use AT&T Syntax**:

**calc.S**:

```
.data
hello:
    .string "Hello World\n"

.globl  main
main:
    movl $4, %eax
    movl $1, %ebx
    movl $hello,%ecx
    movl $12,%edx
    int $0x80

    ret
```

**calc.pro**:

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= qt

SOURCES += \
    calc.S
```

Paste these 2 files in the same directory then execute `qmake` , followed by `make`.

**Output:**

```
$ ./calc 
Hello World
```

Comment: Thanks. I c that kills all the QT and C++ build steps. Thus only allowing for projects which are pure assembly. I take it mixing full assembly src files, and C++/Qt src files in a Qt project is not possible?

Comment: Updated answer. The issue is that you are using Intel syntax. Check my example.

Comment: Thanks, so I need to use AT&T style with GCC? I tried what you suggested, code in original post, got error.

Comment: I added the full example. It works on my Linux with gcc/g++. If you have any problems, you will have to paste the error here. I suggest you create a new folder to perform the test above.

Comment: Doesn't work. I see you're on Linux. Interesting. Using Win XP here. `WinMain@16' error.

Comment: Interesting is that you tell us that it doesn't work, but you don't share what exactly is the error (or error msg) you are observing. Can't help you any further, good luck.

Comment: The fact is that if GCC is able to compile *calc.S* on the cmd-line with `gcc calc.S -o calc` it should work with qmake/make.

Comment: Karl, I do tell you the error messg. Look at the top of this page. :) Look in section EDIT 2. I posted the code I tried based on your suggestion before you posted the same code, I also copy pasted the exact error messages.

Comment: undefined reference to `WinMain@16'

Comment: Thanks, it wasn't clear to me that you were having **the same error** as before. I don't have a Windows box setup for this test, but I suggest you start to [read about this error here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5259714/176769).

Comment: Just to clarify a few things, if you try to build a simple .pro file that compiles a minimal C++ application (hello world), this problem you are reporting happens or not?

Comment: Everything works ok as long as I don't try to add any assembly.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `SOURCES += yourfile.asm` in your *.pro file?

Comment: It is not clear, which compiler would be used for assembly here? gcc/g++?  That is what comes with Qt and that is what I have selected. This only supports inline assembly right (which does not support many things like labels and .data section)?

Comment: @L123 Wrong. `gcc` does support translating assembly files (`*.s`) to object code. And it does support inline assembly, which may even contain pseudo ops like ".data" and jumps to local labels defined in the inline assembly. It is only you who doesn't know about this, read the gcc online docs and the chapter about inline assembly.