# Trying to use class files, getting "undefined reference to `WinMain@16'" error

Tags: c++, class

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [undefined reference to `WinMain@16'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5259714/undefined-reference-to-winmain16)

I am building an application that calculates travel time necessary to reach a user selected destination from predetermined city based upon an estimated travel speed determined by the user. For this program I am to utilize classes/class source files. When compiling my source file I continuously get the error “undefined reference to `WinMain@16’” and due to my being unfamiliar with the usage of source files I am not sure how to fix this issue. Any help would be appreciated with regard to pointing me in the right direction as to properly utilizing source files. Thanks in advance for the help.

Header file:

```
 #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    class Trip
    {
        private:
            string destination;
            double distance;

        public:
            void TripValue(string b, double c);
            void TripTime(Trip *a);
    };
```

Source File:

```
#include "Trip.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void Trip::TripValue(string b, double c)
{
    destination = b;
    distance = c;
}

void Trip::TripTime(Trip *a)
{
    double user_speed;
    double time;

    cout << "Please enter your estimated travel speed in miles per hour: ";
    cin >> user_speed;
    cout << endl;

    time = (a->distance / user_speed);

    cout << endl;
    cout << "Your estimated travel time to " << a->destination << " is "
        << time << " hours.\n";
    cout << endl;
}
```

Application code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Trip.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Trip StL, Indy, Det, Nash, Dal, Den, NY, LA, Mia, Sea;

    int choice;

    StL.TripValue("St. Louis", 297.34);
    Indy.TripValue("Indianapolis", 184.78);
    Det.TripValue("Detroit", 282.73);
    Nash.TripValue("Nashville", 441.02);
    Dal.TripValue("Dallas", 925.91);
    Den.TripValue("Denver", 1004.93);
    NY.TripValue("New York", 791.50);
    LA.TripValue("Los Angeles", 2017.74);
    Mia.TripValue("Miami", 1363.55);
    Sea.TripValue("Seattle", 2032.31);

    do
    {
        cout << "=================================Trip Calulator=================================\n";
        cout << "Select your destination from Chicago:\n";
        cout << endl;
        cout << " 1. St. Louis\n";
        cout << " 2. Indianapolis\n";
        cout << " 3. Detroit\n";
        cout << " 4. Nashville\n";
        cout << " 5. Dallas\n";
        cout << " 6. Denver\n";
        cout << " 7. New York\n";
        cout << " 8. Los Angeles\n";
        cout << " 9. Miami\n";
        cout << "10. Seattle\n";
        cout << endl;
        cout << " 0. Exit\n";
        cout << "================================================================================\n";

        cin >> choice;

        cout << endl;

        switch (choice)
        {
            case 1:
                StL.TripTime(&StL);
                break;
            case 2:
                Indy.TripTime(&Indy);
                break;
            case 3:
                Det.TripTime(&Det);
                break;
            case 4:
                Nash.TripTime(&Nash);
                break;
            case 5:
                Dal.TripTime(&Dal);
                break;
            case 6:
                Den.TripTime(&Den);
                break;
            case 7:
                NY.TripTime(&NY);
                break;
            case 8:
                LA.TripTime(&LA);
                break;
            case 9:
                Mia.TripTime(&Mia);
                break;
            case 10:
                Sea.TripTime(&Sea);
                break;
        }
    } while (choice != 0);
}
```

Comment: Are you compiling the one with `main` as a console application?

Comment: I suspect you are using Visual C++ and did *not* select console application as the project type.

Comment: I'm using Code::Blocks and just compiling it as I would any other program. As I noted in my original post, while I have utilized classes in the past, class files are completely foreign to me so any additional procedure necessary to properly implement them is something I am not currently aware of.

Comment: Why you haven`t included header for <string>?

Answer (score 1):

Thats a linker problem.

Try to change Properties -> Linker -> System -> SubSystem

from Windows (/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS) to Console (/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE)