# Code::Blocks, MinGW, libsdl, and GNU C++ compiler: undefined reference to `WinMain@16

Tags: c++, mingw, codeblocks

I have been trying to compile the most basic SDL application, but no matter what I do I keep getting this error:

```
c:/program files (x86)/codeblocks/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.1/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):main.c:(.text+0xd2): undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
```

I searched for solutions for this, but they all had to do with either Visual C++ or a missing main. I am not using Visual C++, and I have defined main.

Here's my code:

```
#include "SDL/SDL.h"

int main( int argc, char* args[] )
{
    //Start SDL
    SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING );

    //Quit SDL
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: make sure you don't have `main` inside a namespace. And link against `-lmingw32`

Comment: try this link: (you may tried already) http://wiki.libsdl.org/moin.fcg/FAQWindows

Comment: I went to the linker settings in Code::blocks and under "Other linker options" I put "-lmingw32 -lSDLmain -lSDL -mwindows", but I still get the error.

Comment: Have you looked here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5259714/undefined-reference-to-winmain16

Comment: Yes, but I'm using the GNU compiler and the -mwindows flag.

Answer (score 6):

Don't use "Other linker options". Use the "Link libraries" section. Add the following items.

```
mingw32
SDLmain
SDL
```

You can put `-mwindows` in the "Other linker options" section.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else comes across this, I put -lmingw32 *after* -lSDLmain and -lSDL which caused this issue for me. Putting -lmingw32 first fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error in a project of mine that I want to compile both on linux and windows.
I use a makefile to compile the project.
A solution that has worked for me, although I admit it is a bit of a hack is adding this to main.cpp (wherever your main function would be)

```
extern "C" {

    int WinMain(int argc, char** argv)
    {
        return main(argc, argv);
    }
}
```

This makes the linker find WinMain and use it as the entry point in the program. I can also hope that this solution doesn't break linux compilability, hopefully it will be considered just an unused function.