# mingw, collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status error

Tags: c, eclipse, mingw

First of all i want to make it clear that i just started studying the "C language" at uni.
I'm at the beginning so i might not be able to understand what you guys say using specific words and such.
This is also why i found most of the other topics regarding my same problem kinda useless: i couldn't understand much.
Anyway, here we go.
I installed today in my pc mingw, the latest version; i followed every single note i found in the download page.
I installed then eclipse (these two softwares were suggested by our teacher).
Problem is: whenever i try to compile a little program such as

```
/*
 * Esercitazione.c
 *
 *  Created on: 08/apr/2013
 *      Author: Fra
 */

#include<stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    printf("Hello world! \n");
    return (0);
}
```

i get this error http://puu.sh/2wrk2 
"Well let's try with the old fashioned comand prompt then." i thought.
So i headed to my folder and used the comand "gcc FirstProgram Esercitazione.c".
Now, another problem: whenever i open the just generated .exe file, i almost can't see it opening: i mean that it opens and closes so fast that it took me quite some effort to notice that in the screen there was actually printed "Hello world!" like in the code.
I don't really know what to do and some help would come really handy right now.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is a `*` in the filename area of the source window. This usually indicates a modified file. Have you saved your file before trying to compile? Also, run the command from within a command window rather than double clicking on it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It helped me a bunch! both the save before compiling and run the comand in the same window.

Comment: Just a last question though.
i'm 99.9% sure that in our teacher's pc, under the console tab there was printed the "Hello World!" sentence, which i can not see now sadly
link: http://puu.sh/2wsLi

Comment: You have to run the command after compiling it. Probably the button that looks like a "Play" button. You should get more help from your instructor. You actually pay him/her to answer these questions for you.

Comment: That's so true! and i will surely do so the next lesson.
meanwhile, thanks a lot. Helped me!

Comment: possible duplicate of [undefined reference to \`WinMain@16'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5259714/undefined-reference-to-winmain16)