# gfortran 4.8.1 on Windows 7 (undefined reference to 'WinMain@16')

Tags: gcc, fortran, gfortran

I have a problem compiling some Fortran code with gfortran 4.8.1 on Windows 7. With some Fortran programs I get the error message:

```
c:/gcc/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-pc-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../i686-pc-mingw32/lib/libmingw32.a(lib32_libmingw32_a-crt0_c.o):crt0_c.c:(.text+0x3c): undefined reference to 'WinMain@16'
```

These are not programs that contain only function or subroutines!

Any help how to solve this problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [undefined reference to \`WinMain@16'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5259714/undefined-reference-to-winmain16)

Comment: @Klaus Rohe: Please clarify what you mean by **these are not programs that contain only function or subroutines**.  Are they programs (i.e. has a program statement) or code that just contains modules/functions/subroutines.  Also does it happen when you are building programs or compiling dependent code.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error when I changed the name of my program to "main", by which I mean

```
program main
    ! do stuff
end program main
```

When I changed it back to its original name (like xxx_main) the problem was resolved. When I encountered the problem, I was linking to an additional object module; I am unable to reproduce this with only a trivial "main" program.

I'm on gfortran 4.10.0 on Windows 10 and cygwin.