# How to integrate and run C and C++ Codes in VS Code after installing mingw? Error is coming

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, mingw, vscode-code-runner

I first installed mingw into my system and added it to the path. It worked. Showing version when I type `gcc --version` in cmd.
Then I reinstalled VS Code, then installed C/C++ Intellisense Extension and Code Runner Extension into the VS Code.
After that, when I am writing even simple Hello World Programs, it is displaying an error as follows.

```
PS E:\C Programming> cd "e:\C Programming\" ; if ($?) { gcc hello-world.c -o hello-world } ; if ($?) { .\hello-world }
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):(.text.startup+0xc0): undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
PS E:\C Programming>
```

What does all this mean? How can this be fixed?

Comment: You created a Windows GUI application (not a console application) and did not have a WinMain function.

Comment: Related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20909816/undefined-reference-to-winmain16](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20909816/undefined-reference-to-winmain16)

Comment: You probably need to show your `tasks.json` for someone to help