# c++ not able to get output in terminal

Tags: c++, visual-studio

[image]

not getting output on terminal

> c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):(.text.startup+0xa0): undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
> collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
> PS C:\Users\pmalh\Desktop\c++> .a.exe
> .a.exe : The module '.a' could not be loaded. For more information, run 'Import-Module .a'.
> At line:1 char:1
> + .a.exe
> + ~~~~~~~
> + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (.a.exe:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
> + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotAutoLoadModule

Comment: .a.exe is not a valid file name.   There is something wrong in your makefile, or link command line, which we cannot see.

Comment: The exact same file was working using the exact same commands few days ago when you asked the a very similar question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69477058/tutorial-from-code-with-harry-a-youtube-channel .  What have you changed(in your system) since then?

Comment: nothing ..really a newbie in coding...shoud i just skip visual code and practice on online compiler??

Comment: The white dot in your tab tells me you have not saved yet. You should explicitly save before trying to compile your file, as presumably your compiler sees a file without a `main` function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20909816/undefined-reference-to-winmain16