# Error message in codeblocks: Undefined reference to 'WinMain@16'

Tags: c++, gcc, codeblocks, winmain

I want to run the following code in Codeblocks 20.03, but I get the error message: `Undefined reference to 'WinMain@16'`.

**Code:**

```
std::string countSheep(int number) 
{
  std::string res;
  std::string s = " sheep...";

  for (int i = 1; i <= number; i++) {
    res += std::to_string(i) + s;
  }

  return res;
}
```

The initial problem was, that I got the error message: *to_string’ is not a member of ‘std*
After that I have updated my GCC compiler to 9.2.0. But now, I keep getting that winmain error message.

Do you have any idea, what to do?

Comment: Do you have a `main()` in your program? Please read about [mcve].

Comment: have a look at this maybe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21500724/c-undefined-reference-to-winmain16-codeblocks

Comment: You are right! The missing main() part caused the problem. I have just realized that source codes on the Codewars webpage are not the full program. But thanks, it helped me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this: [C++ undefined reference to WinMain@16 (Code::Blocks)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21500724/c-undefined-reference-to-winmain16-codeblocks)

and this: [Undefined reference to WinMain@16 - Codeblocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29404780/undefined-reference-to-winmain16-codeblocks)

also regarding your code, maybe some of the more experienced c++ here might tell me I am wrong. But your function countSheep you are not returning anything, you are trying to print res I presume ?
so you are not returning a string that you can use later in a var, you are only printing out.

if that's the case and as I mentioned earlier, others more experienced can tell me I am wrong about this, try this:
`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void countSheep(int number);

int main()
{
   countSheep(3);
}
void countSheep(int number) 
{
        std::string res;
        std::string s = " sheep...";

          for (int i = 1; i <= number; i++) 
          {
                res += std::to_string(i) + s;
                std::cout << res << std::endl;
            }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! The problem was the missing main() function.