# Weird Error when implementing Stack in C

Tags: c, compiler-errors, stack

I'm trying to implement stack in C and it got the weird error in my MinGw compiler

```
 gcc -Wall -o stack stack.c
```

Stack.c

```
#include "stack.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>


Stack *create(int size) {
    Stack *result;
    result = (Stack *) malloc(  sizeof(Stack) * size );
    assert(result != NULL);

    result -> file = result;
    result -> maxAllocate = size;
    result -> top = -1;
    return result;
}
```

stack.h

```
#define MAX_SIZE 1024

typedef struct {
    void **file;    
    int top;     
    int maxAllocate; // current size of array allocated for stack
} Stack;

Stack *create(int size);        
int   push(Stack *s, void *x);  
void  *pop(Stack *s);           
int   isEmpty(Stack *s);
```

error

```
C:\test>gcc -Wall -o stack stack.c
stack.c: In function 'create':
stack.c:26:17: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by de
fault]
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o): In function
 `main':
C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\src\mingwrt/../mingw/main.c:73: undefined reference to `WinMai
n@16'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Please provide error you have got

Comment: `result -> file = result;`  looks like incorrect, should be `result -> file = &result;`

Comment: yes updated with error, sorry about that

Comment: warning here but error in `main.c` where is `main`?

Comment: result is a Stack* and you are setting result->file (a void**) to it. Those are mismatching types; follow @Dabo 's advice

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5259714/undefined-reference-to-winmain16

Comment: You have two errors. Which is the _weird_ one that you're asking about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using `gcc` with `-o` option means you want to compile, link and run your program (this command won't run it, but usually that's the reason with such usage). You cannot run a program without an `entry point` (in this case it's `main` function).

If you only want to check if your `stack.c` compiles use `gcc -Wall -c stack.c`.

Answer (score 3):

With `gcc -Wall -o stack stack.c` you compile only `stack.c` (which has o main function in it) but for a functioning application you will also need a `main` function, as the main entry point: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entry_point