# Unable to compile c code using mingw on eclipse windows

Tags: mingw

When i am trying to compile c code on eclipse using mingw. getting below error.

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):(.text.startup+0xa7): 
 undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
```

how can i resolve this error.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why did you tag as 'linux'?

Comment: The error is at link time, that means it compiles fine. However, WinMain is not declared. On Windows, the standard entry point is `WinMain`, not `main`. I'm sure there's a linker flag you have to set, but I don't know which.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [undefined reference to \`WinMain@16'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5259714/undefined-reference-to-winmain16)

Comment: Does your program have a WinMain (or main())?