# writting a c++ class, but i need a hand

Tags: c++, class

is this well written ? did i do anything wrong ?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"
using namespace std;
class rectangleclass
{
    int w,h;
  public:
        void setnum(int x, int y)
        {
        w=x;
        h=y;
    }
    int area() 
        {
            return w*h;
        }
};
int main()
{
    rectangleclass ra;
ra.setnum(7,2);
cout<<ra.area();
return 0;
```

}
im getting two different errors
Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _WinMain@16 referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup MSVCRTD.lib
and
Error   2   fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

Comment: I guess you're using Visual Studio.  If so, you chose the wrong project type.  You should be choosing "Console", not "Win32".

Comment: As to "well written", what would happen if you called `ra.area()` immediately after you declared `ra`?

Comment: Specifically [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5260237/1413395) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22160071/1413395)

Comment: thank you i got that fixed, but when the console opened up it lasted a second before closing....any reason ?

Comment: @RidaHelbawi The reason why the console opens and closes is because the program executes exactly what you've written -- it isn't obligated or required to do anything else.  Nothing you wrote stops the console from closing.  Either place a statement to "pause" the console (whatever that is), or simply run your application in a command window.

Comment: i removed the return 0; and replaced it with system("pause");

Comment: if i called ra.area() immediatly after ra i get 687194768. what is this ?

Comment: @RidaHelbawi So I guess your class is not "well written".  You failed to initialize your member variables on construction of the `rectangleclass` object.  So the code exhibits undefined behavior.

Comment: its my first try... how do u recommend to improve/fix it ?