# what is undefined reference to `WinMain@16

Tags: c++, c, winmain

I started recently with programming and this is what I wrote:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int a,b,c;

    a=2;
    b=7;
    c=a+b;

    printf ("c vale %d\n;c");

    return 0;
}
```

Something simple I thought but then this error tends to appear:

> C:/MinGW/i686-pc-mingw32/lib/libmingw32.a(lib32_libmingw32_a-crt0_c.o):crt0_c.c:(.text+0x3c):
>   undefined reference to `WinMain@16'

can anyone explain me step by step what should I fix?

Comment: This happens when you attempt to compile the program as a windowed app instead of a console app.

Comment: How are you compiling? Please post the full command line (it seems you are using MinGW, probably incorrectly).

Comment: See if [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5259714/undefined-reference-to-winmain16?rq=1) helps you. Note that you gave `printf` one too few arguments, which the compiler is capable of warning about.

Comment: C is not C++ is not C! Pick a language!

Comment: `main` and `WinMain` is basically the same in both C and C++.

Comment: Please do at least a basic search for the error message before posting a new question. This has clearly been asked (and answered) here before.

Comment: "can anyone explain me step by step what should I fix?" Yes. Next question?

Comment: @user3386109 pssh, typos. should be `printf("c value %d\n", c);` (clearly)

Answer (score 0):

Compile as console and change this line

```
   printf ("c vale %d\n;c");
```

to

```
    printf ("c vale %d\n", c);  // vale or value ???
```

Comment: _Compile as console_ isn't that informative. If one has to ask this kind of question, one isn't likely to know how to change that information.

Comment: I agree with Tas. Although *"compile as console"* is correct, it's not helpful unless you explain *how* to compile as console.