# undefined reference to `WinMain@16' MinGW

Tags: c++

Recently started trying to create DLLs in C++ and have been trying to create a generic user prompt class for command line input. When I try to compile the code I get the following error in the .cpp:

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):(.text.startup+0xa7): undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make.exe": *** [userPrompt] Error 1
```

Doing some reading on the error led me to believe that this occurs when there's no main function in the file -- If this is the case how do I avoid this when trying to make a .cpp file for the purpose of putting it in a library?

My current compiler is MinGW and my current IDE is NetBeans.

**EDIT:** As requested, full command line logs for the compile
Additionally, [undefined reference to `WinMain@16'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5259714/undefined-reference-to-winmain16/5260237#5260237) (As linked in the answer posted as a duplicate) implies in the answer that a main or WinMain is required somewhere in a .cpp file for it to compile, a part of the question asked above (And I'm sorry if this was unclear) is if that is actually the case, and if it is not how do I circumvent this restriction?

```
g++     userPrompt.cpp   -o userPrompt
userPrompt.cpp:33:54: warning: non-static data member initializers only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 [enabled by default]
         const string strCommands[2] = {"HELP", "QUIT"}; // Array of all valid commands.
                                                      ^
userPrompt.cpp:34:92: warning: non-static data member initializers only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 [enabled by default]
         const string strHelpText[2] = {"to re-list these commands.", "to exit this prompt."}; // Parallel array of help texts for valid commands.
                                                                                            ^
userPrompt.cpp:38:17: warning: non-static data member initializers only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 [enabled by default]
                 "==================================================\n";
                 ^
userPrompt.cpp:33:54: warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 [enabled by default]
         const string strCommands[2] = {"HELP", "QUIT"}; // Array of all valid commands.
                                                      ^
userPrompt.cpp:34:92: warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 [enabled by default]
         const string strHelpText[2] = {"to re-list these commands.", "to exit this prompt."}; // Parallel array of help texts for valid commands.
                                                                                            ^
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):(.text.startup+0xa7): undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make.exe": *** [userPrompt] Error 1

BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 504ms)
```

Comment: How do you use your compiler? Please show us the command line.

Comment: If you're building a DLL, why is the name of the output file `collect2.exe`?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I guess `collect2.exe` is not the name of the output file but the name of the tool.

Comment: Also, library generally refers to code you statically link to vs. shared library/DLL which is loaded dynamically at runtime and the necessary code may be different as well as the file extension.

Comment: @MikeCAT
Updated the post with the full logs from the attempted compile.
Also, if it's at all important, I'm using the NetBeans IDE.

Comment: I guess you should set the "project option" of your IDE to have it build a DLL.