# using windows.h along with main()

Tags: c, winapi, program-entry-point

I must use main() and call a function from `windows.h`.

The following code wants a `WinMain()` function to be used instead of `main()`.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int vk_Shift = 16;

    while (1)
    {
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(vk_Shift) < 0)
        {
            printf("Shift is pressed\n");
        }
    }
}
```

**Error**

```
Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _WinMain@16 
referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup   

Error   2   error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

How can I get this work in VS2013?

Comment: I'm not using VS for C code, but I guess configuring it as "console" application should do the trick.

Comment: Why "must" you use main()? But, as @FelixPalmen points out, console applications use "main" as their entry point and GUI applications (by default) use WinMain. I don't know if there is a setting, perhaps you just need to recreate the app as a console app. Or just change the Linkers /SUBSYSTEM flag from WINDOWS to CONSOLE.

Comment: @ChrisBecke, I am writing a console application.

Comment: Doing good for me on VS2010.... tested on a empty project.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix) and [Unresolved external symbol _WinMain@16](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5259714/62576) and about three dozen others asking about *Unresolved external symbol _WinMain@16*

Comment: "*The following code wants a `WinMain()` function to be used instead of `main()`*" - the **code** doesn't care what entry point you use. It is all the same from the API's perspective.  The **project** cares.  You are clearly compiling the code in a GUI project, rather than a console project.  You need to adjust your project settings accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, guys, I got it.

[Felix Palmen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2371524/felix-palmen)'s advice works.

> ... ... I guess configuring it as "console" application should do the trick.

So, what I did is, I changed my project's preference from `WIDOWS` to `CONSOLE`.

[image]

Comment: This is far from an exhaustive analysis. Sorry, -1.