# Cannot compile C programs on CodeBlocks: Undefined reference to 'WinMain@16'

Tags: c, linker-errors

I'm new to C and I'm trying to compile a HelloWorld program. I'm using GNU GCC 4.9.2. I've looked online for many solutions but none of them worked: Every time I compile the program, it hits me with this error:

```
"Undefined reference to 'WinMain@16'"
```

Please bear in mind that I HAVE configured the project as a console project, not a windows project and that I have written the main function correctly.

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello world!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Finally, note that I can successfully compile, build, and run C++ programs with code blocks. For some reason, I can't do the same for C. Additionally, I tried compiling the source file from the command line and the issue still persisted.

Compilation lines:

[image]

Comment: Look at the actual compilation commands issued by code blocks.

Comment: Can you clarify, please? I'm new to C.

Comment: It has nothing to do with C per se. Codeblocks runs gcc as an external command. You need to identify the exact parameters of the command. Look at the compiler output window and try to find a line that has the word gcc in it.

Comment: I updated the post.

Comment: This is not the actual command. It is just an info line.

Comment: I updated it again.

Comment: You have said you are using gcc 4.9.2 but the command references gcc 6.3.0. Perhaps your gcc installation is somehow broken. Can you do the same thing with a c++ program and compare the results?

Comment: Just google the error message.  Too many to choose from, even on this site, but say https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5259714/undefined-reference-to-winmain16

Comment: Well, as stated in the post, I've already done that. The C++ program executes correctly and prints "Hello, World!", while the C program doesn't. (Undefined reference to winmain@16")

Answer (score -1):

I solved the problem and I don't know how. I changed the C debugger from gcc to gnu, it gave me a different error. I then changed it back to gcc and it started working randomly. I've been trying to solve this problem for literally 6 hours. Then I try some random nonsense and guess what? it works.

I hate software development.

I love software development.