# How do I resolve the issue so the code runs properly?

Tags: c++

Whenever I try to run the code, it gives some error. How to resolve that?

[image]

**EDIT**
After correcting ; it still shows this:

```
PS C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\C++> cd "c:\Users\Dell\Desktop\C++\" ; if ($?) { g++ test.cpp -o test } ; if ($?) { .\test }
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):(.text.startup+0xc0): undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Semi-colon......

Comment: Please don't *ever* post images of code. Post code as *text*. Same goes for error messages.

Comment: [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12573816/5910058)

Comment: The error is exactly this one from the previous comment link: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5259714/undefined-reference-to-winmain16/5260237#5260237](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5259714/undefined-reference-to-winmain16/5260237#5260237)

Comment: @drescherjm I suggest closing as a duplicate of that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: make sure you save your file before compiling it

Comment: My IDE doesn't accept images.  My IDE can't extract the text from the image.  No code posted as text == no help.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you configured project as some type of "Windows application" instead of "console application"

In programming there are those pieces called "functions" and classical c++ application is started by calling function called "main", but widows application use "WinMain" instead so it tries to find "WinMain" which does not exists, try to create new project and make sure it's some kind of "consol application" not "windows application" since even if you change main to WinMain it still might cause more problems in future.

Answer (score 0):

Put Semicolon `";"` at the end of line 5
Please read about c++ more :)

Comment: After correcting that also, it doesn't run.