# Sublime text 3 giving error upon compilation

Tags: c++, c++11, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I have recently installed sublime text 3 on my pc and trying to run some c++ code on it , it is giving me the following error, could someone please help, thanks for your time. I have put my cpp code and the error appearing:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
#define ll long long
#define pb push_back
#define endl "\n"
ll mod=1000000007;
#define IOS ios::sync_with_stdio(0); cin.tie(0); cout.tie(0);
int main()
{
    IOS;
    #ifndef ONLINE_JUDGE
    freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin);
    freopen("output.txt", "w", stdout);
    #endif

    ll t;cin>>t;while(t--)
    {
        ll a;
        cin>>a;
        cout<<a+2;

    }
}

    c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):(.text.startup+0xc0): undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
[Finished in 0.3s with exit code 1]
```

Comment: Seems related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5259714/undefined-reference-to-winmain16