# compiling sdl simple program in dev C++ shows undefined reference to `WinMain'

Tags: c++, sdl, dev-c++

My version of DEV C++ is **5.11** and I have used version **SDL2-2.0.12** and OS is **Windows 10**.
Folder path of `sdl.h` file is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\SDL2-2.0.12\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\SDL2`

I have done my project settings as shown in ::
[https://thenumbat.github.io/cpp-course/sdl2/01/devSetup.html#:~:text=Open%20up%20your%20project%20and,and%20select%20the%20lib%20folder](https://thenumbat.github.io/cpp-course/sdl2/01/devSetup.html#:%7E:text=Open%20up%20your%20project%20and,and%20select%20the%20lib%20folder).

My program

```
#include <iostream>
#include "SDL.h"

using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char* args[] )
{
  
        if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) < 0) 
        {
            cout << "SDL init failed.\n";
            return 1;
        }       
        
        SDL_Quit();    
        return 0;    
}
```

While compiling I am getting such message::

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\libmingw32.a(lib64_libmingw32_a-crt0_c.o) In function `main':

C:\crossdev\src\mingw-w64-v3-git\mingw-w64-crt\crt\crt0_c.c undefined reference to `WinMain'

------ this is in red color ---------
C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\SDL2-2.0.12\x86_64-w64-mingw32\collect2.exe  [Error] ld returned 1 exit status

C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\SDL2-2.0.12\x86_64-w64-mingw32\Makefile.win  recipe for target 'SDLproj1.exe' failed
```

Please see the attached image.

[image]

Comment: this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5259714/undefined-reference-to-winmain16/5260237#5260237

Comment: Can you provide the contents of the `Compile Log` tab?

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. OP uses MinGW, so it doesn't seem to apply. The problem is related to SDL2's `#define main ...`, but I'm not sure what exactly is going on here.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat SDL does `#define main` but the undefined symbol is WinMain. The comments is SDL_main.h say "Windows SDL provides WinMain()" so one needs to link to SDL2main.lib that provides it, see https://wiki.libsdl.org/FAQWindows