# whenever I run my program in visual studio code I get "undefined reference to `WinMain'" could anyone explain what the problem is?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I have just started learning C++ in Visual Studio code but for some reason, it is showing error but when I tried the same program on Devc++ I was able to get the desired output.

MY PROGRAM [my program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHq2p.png)

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() 

{
    
cout<<"Hello world";
    
return 0;

}
```

This is the error that is flashing in the output:

ERROR:[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5lMti.png) [error contd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ZygT.png)

> [Running] cd "c:\Users\Swastik\Documents\c++" && g++ helloworld.cpp
> -o helloworld && "c:\Users\Swastik\Documents\c++"helloworld C:/Program
> Files/mingw-w64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/libmingw32.a(lib64_libmingw32_a-crt0_c.o):crt0_c.c:(.text.startup+0x2e):
> undefined reference to `WinMain' collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1
> exit status
>
> [Done] exited with code=1 in 3.226 seconds

Comment: Your project is configured to build a Windows application, not a Console application.

Comment: @paddy, [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5259714/undefined-reference-to-winmain16/5260237#5260237) suggests that GCC should work with `main` regardless of subsystem and without any particular compiler/linker flags.