# I got a error message "undefined reference to `WinMain'"

Tags: c, priority-queue

This is my priority queue practicing code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX_ELEMENT 200

typedef struct{
    int key;
}element;


typedef struct{
    element heap[MAX_ELEMENT];
    int heap_size;
}HeapType;

// create function
HeapType* create()
{
    return (HeapType*)malloc(sizeof(HeapType)); 
}

// initialization function
void init(HeapType*h)
{
    h->heap_size = 0;   
}
```

When I compile this code, I got a message "undefined reference to `WinMain'"
The program informed me that there was a problem on this line > 'return (HeapType*)malloc(sizeof(HeapType));    '

What can I do for this problem?

Comment: You don't have a `main` function. Is that expected?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [undefined reference to \`WinMain@16'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5259714/undefined-reference-to-winmain16)

Answer (score 2):

To have a complete working program, you have to have a main() function. For example this one:

```
void main(void)
{
    HeapType *Heap;

    Heap = create();
    init(Heap);
}
```

Obviously, your code is largely incomplete...

Answer (score 0):

Without the `main` code your program is incomplete and it will give you problems.
Try to include `void main(void){}` in your program and then see if the problem exist.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you don't have a `main` function. `main` is the entry point to all applications(except GUI applications in Windows, the entry point is `WinMain`). If your program had no entry point, how's it supposed to start?, it can't start, hence the error.

Add a `main` function.

```
int main() {
    /* Do all the stuff here,
    it seems you want to do things with your structs,
    do it here */
}
```

If your problem persists, make sure your application isn't marked as GUI, make sure gcc flags like `-mwindows` or `-Wl,-subsystem,windows` are not present.