# Why is VS code editor not running the code

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am new to programming and I am having some issues with the code, it is not running, I think its because of some directory issue, I tried uninstalling and re-installing the compiler but the problem still persists, here is the error it shows

```
C:/Program Files (x86)/mingw-w64/i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/libmingw32.a(lib32_libmingw32_a-crt0_c.o):crt0_c.c:(.text.startup+0x39): undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

any explanations?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [undefined reference to \`WinMain@16'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5259714/undefined-reference-to-winmain16)

Comment: Without the code, it's hard to say, but the error you provide is generally linked to `main()` is not declared.

Comment: Just putting *undefined reference to `WinMain@16'* into your favorite search engine should have been enough to figure it out.