# Running g++ on VS code: undefined reference to `WinMain'

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, g++

This is what it looks like on VS code terminal when I run the code.

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6

PS D:\C C++> cd "d:\C C++\" ; if ($?) { g++ TEST.C -o TEST } ; if ($?) { .\TEST }
D:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/libmingw32.a(lib64_libmingw32_a-crt0_c.o): in function `main':
C:/M/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/crt/crt0_c.c:18: undefined reference to `WinMain'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
PS D:\C C++>
```

This is the simple program I tried to run.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    int age;
    printf("Enter age\n");
    scanf("%d",&age);
    printf("age is %d",age);
    return 0;
}
```

[screenshot of the program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUPmb.png)

Comment: I've never seen anyone try to run code like that. The simple gcc myCode.c -o myCode.exe doesn't work?

Comment: Save the file before running the program, it should solve the error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [undefined reference to \`WinMain@16'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5259714/undefined-reference-to-winmain16)

Comment: Yes, I just have to save it. I forgot that the autosave is off, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Save the file as said by **@Gaurav Pathak** and check if you've set the path to the compiler.

Try to run `gcc a.c -o a.exe` for once, sometimes the code runner does something unexpected.