# LNK2019 unreferenced function main

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm creating a d3d12 project from the blank c++ windows template and am geting this error:

1>MSVCRTD.lib(exe_main.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol main referenced in function "int __cdecl invoke_main(void)" (?invoke_main@@YAHXZ)

I read another post that said something about the msvc runtime library not being linked since it is a blank template? That can't be the issue in my case right? I already tried linking the files found at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/crt-library-features?view=msvc-170#c-standard-library-stl-lib-files, and as expected, nothing changes.

here is my code (c20):

```cpp
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <Windows.h>
#include <WinUser.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <optional>

LRESULT CALLBACK MainWndProc
( // main window lifecycle manager
    HWND hwnd, // handle to the associated window
    UINT uMsg, // message identifier
    WPARAM wParam, // first mesage parameter
    LPARAM lParam // second message paremeter
)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
        // init adapters, create swapchain, and prepare sample
        std::cout << "in lfcm" << std::endl;
        return LRESULT(0);
    case WM_SIZE:
        // resize swapchain
        return LRESULT(0);
    case WM_DESTROY:
        // cleanup
        return LRESULT(0);
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return LRESULT(0);

};

std::optional<HWND> WinInit(HINSTANCE hInstance) { // window creation factory // register window class, create window, TODO: initialize swapchain

    // create and configure the window class

    wchar_t WCLANN[] = L"window class";

    WNDCLASS cl = {};
    HWND hWnd;
    ZeroMemory(&cl, sizeof(WNDCLASS)); // pretty self explanatory

    cl.lpfnWndProc = MainWndProc;
    cl.hInstance = hInstance;
    cl.lpszClassName = WCLANN;

    RegisterClass(&cl); // register the window class

    hWnd = CreateWindowEx
    (
        0, // window styles (optional)
        WCLANN, // associated window class
        L"Window text", // Window text
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, // Window style

        CW_USEDEFAULT, // use default x 
        CW_USEDEFAULT, // use default y
        1280, // width
        720, // height

        NULL, // Parent window
        NULL, // Menu
        hInstance, // Instance handle
        NULL // additional application data
    );

    if (hWnd == HWND(0))
    {
        // window creation factory failed; return
        return std::nullopt;
    }

    return hWnd;

};

int APIENTRY WinMain
( // windows specific program entrypoint
    _In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
    _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    _In_ LPSTR lpCmdLine,
    _In_ int nCmdShow
)
{
    std::optional<HWND> inVT = WinInit(hInstance); // CHANGE TO REFLECT OPTIONAL CHANGES
    if (inVT.has_value()) // window creation succeeded, window handle returned
    {
        // do something with the handle to the window
        std::cout << inVT.value();
    }
    else // window creation failed, no window handle to return
    {
        // log
        std::cout << "window creation factory failure" << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "window created" << std::endl;

    while (true) {}; // ??? why won't this work???

}
```

I've never had this happen to me before?

Comment: Something in the project settings is wrong; the compiler is building a normal C++ program and not a Windows program. Sorry, don't know beyond that.

Comment: @RaymondChen -- no, that's too generic an answer. The problem here is specifically about `WinMain` versus `main` as the entry point for the program.

Comment: @PeteBecker probably subsystem console instead gui

Comment: @PeteBecker I mean to link to [this specific answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5259714/undefined-reference-to-winmain16/5260237#5260237) which discusses the subsystem issue.

Comment: @RaymondChen — that addresses the problem, but it’s for command-line tools. The answer below isn’t as verbose, but it seems to have solved the problem.

Comment: *"The answer below isn’t as verbose"* - Between verbose and correct, I will always go with the latter. *"it seems to have solved the problem"* - It didn't. It's a heavy-handed procedure to make the problem disappear, but not a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used the console application template but the code is for a Windows application.

There are ways to adjust the settings to make it a Windows application, but the easiest solution since you don't have much code is to make a new project from the Windows application template, copy the code and delete the old project.

Comment: would I just use empty project then?

Comment: @LukeWright you'd use the windows application template...........

Comment: no any sense begin new project, copy-paste, etc. simply change subsystem and all

Comment: @RbMm are you sure that's the only difference between the windows template and the console template? I'm not sure it's the only difference.

Comment: yes, i sure and have perfect knowledge and experience here

Comment: *"Perfect knowledge"* is stretching it, but yes, changing the [`/SUBSYSTEM`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/subsystem-specify-subsystem) is all that's required, and it is indeed the only difference.